# how to fill colors between contours in matlab

Tags: matlab, colors, contour

I have plotted multiple contours in matlab with the hold on command, using the contour function of MatLab. How can I go ahead if I want to fill color between the first and the last contour. I tried contourf function but it didnt work out that way.

Thanks in advance.

I have written two simple lines which plots the zero level set contour after every iterations.

```
      hold on;
      contour(X,Y,phi,[0,0],'r');
```

Comment: Can you provide an example plot of what you have and what you want instead? How do you plot contours with the hold on? Can you share some code?

Comment: @Schorsch Sorry I couldnt upload the plot due to some threshold limit on reputations. My plot is having multiple contours and what I want is to fill color between the contours.

Comment: can you post the plot somewhere else and link to it?

Comment: Have you checked `contourf` function?

Comment: @Schorsch Here is the link to the image. https://www.dropbox.com/s/82st6xtadso3036/LeftCoenerInterpolated_RightCornerSame.png

Comment: @anandr Yes i have tried the simple contourf function, I want to fill color between two contours, please tell if we can do that by adding another argument to contourf.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using the `get` command to get individual components from the graph. For example:

```
[x, y, z] = peaks; % Generate some data
figure; surf(x, y, z); % Show
figure;[c, h] = contourf(x, y, z, [0 0]); % Build and show contour plot
patches = get(h, 'children'); % Get different patches
set(patches(1), 'facecolor', 'r') % Colour one red
```

Comment: With this method I can get the contour of my choice colored, but I want to fill color between the contours. Say between initial phi and phi after 10 iterations.

Comment: @Sagar You need to share all the relevant code, otherwise we can't help you.